# Reset Filter And Search Not Working In Admin Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

In My Custom Module, In Admin Grid **Reset Filter And Search Button** Not Working.

Here Is My **Grid.php** Code.

**C:\xampp2\htdocs\testmagento\app\code\local\Sigmasolve\Makemodel\Block\Adminhtml\Makemodel\Grid.php**

```
<?php

class Sigmasolve_Makemodel_Block_Adminhtml_Makemodel_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('makemodelGrid');
        // This is the primary key of the database
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('makemodel');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Delete'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete', array('' => '')),
             'confirm'  => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));

       //$statuses = Mage::getSingleton('makemodel/status')->getOptionArray();

        // array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        // $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
             // 'label'=> Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Change status'),
             // 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
             // 'additional' => array(
                    // 'visibility' => array(
                         // 'name' => 'status',
                         // 'type' => 'select',
                         // 'class' => 'required-entry',
                         // 'label' => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Status'),
                         // 'values' => $statuse 
                    //)
                 //)
        // ));
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('makemodel/makemodel')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('ID'),
            'align'     =>'right',
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'id',  
        ));

        $this->addColumn('ktyp', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Ktyp'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'ktyp',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('manufacturer', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Manufacturer'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'manufacturer',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('model', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Model'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'model',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('capacity', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Capacity'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'capacity',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('year_from', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Year_From'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'year_from',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('year_to', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Year_To'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'year_to',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('fuel', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('makemodel')->__('Fuel'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'fuel',
        ));



        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }



    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
      return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));

    }

}
```

[image]

**When I Click Reset Filter Or Search Button It Is Go To Front End**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I Found My Mistake.
I Forgot Write Code in My Controller File.

```
public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('makemodel/adminhtml_makemodel_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }
```

So, that's why Code is not working.
Thanks for Help...

Comment: Please accept your answer so as the question doesn't pop up randomly some months from now.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this in your `Grid.php` File :

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('makemodelGrid');
    // This is the primary key of the database
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

Comment: i Have Already Tried it, it is not working

Comment: Add this line `$this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);` above `$this->setUseAjax(true);`

Comment: it is also not working